# Rails ActiveJob can't load aws-sdk-transcribeservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-sdk, rails-activejob, amazon-transcribe, aws-sdk-ruby

In my Rails application, I need to use AWS Transcribe service. But, when I tried to create the AWS client from inside ActiveJob, the Sidekiq log always gives me `NameError: uninitialized constant Aws::TranscribeService`. But, when I tried to create the client directly from the Rails console, it doesn't complain. Here is my code.

**/app/job/transcribe_audio_job.rb**

```
class TranscribeAudioJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(job_id)
    job = TranscriptionJob.find(job_id)
    
    # This line always show: NameError: uninitialized constant Aws::TranscribeService
    client = Aws::TranscribeService::Client.new(
      region: 'eu-west-1'
    )

    p client
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
# AWS SDK
gem 'aws-sdk-rails', '~> 3'
gem 'aws-sdk-transcribeservice', '~> 1.50'
```

That code above is working if I try directly in the Rails console.

```
client = Aws::TranscribeService::Client.new(
  region: 'eu-west-1'
)

# <Aws::TranscribeService::Client> <- The result in the Rails console
```

How's the correct way to use the AWS SDK from ActiveJob? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would try adding `require 'aws-sdk-transcribeservice'` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Do you have any `Aws` folder in your app and you use it as an namespace?

Comment: Thanks, Ariejuod. Your suggestion is working. I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Arieljuod in the comment works. Here's the complete code:

**/app/job/transcribe_audio_job.rb**

```
require 'aws-sdk-transcribeservice'

class TranscribeAudioJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(job_id)
    job = TranscriptionJob.find(job_id)
    client = Aws::TranscribeService::Client.new(
      region: 'eu-west-1'
    )

    p client
  end
end
```